# XML request with dynamically loaded xml gives null

Tags: php, xml, ajax, request

Any ideas why the when using ajax requests on a dynamically generated file null is returned but when pasting the content of that file into a static file, the request can execute on the static file correctly?

```
//function to load more data when the user scrolls down.
$(window).scroll(
  function()
  {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
{
      request = createRequest();
  if (request == null)
  {alert("Unable To Create Request");
    }  
    else
{
      <!-- file with xml content is generated in php -->
  var url="/xmlfile.php"; 
      <!-- everthing works when the contents of the output are pasted into this file ->
      <!-- var url="/sample.xml"; -->
  request.open("GET",url,true);
  request.open("GET",url,true);
  request.onreadystatechange = method1;
  request.send(null);
}
  });

  function method1()
  { 
    if (request.readyState == 4) 
{
  if (request.status == 200) 
  {
    var xmldata=request.responseXML; 
    <!-- returns null for php file but valid object for static xml file -->
        alert('xmldata :: '+xmldata);
  }
}
  }
```

As the ready state is checked, should this not mean that the file is completely loaded?

Thanks for any tips.

Da

Comment: My guess would be that your PHP script does not send an appropriate `Content-Type` header, so that it is not recognized as XML when received client-side.

Comment: Thanks. Adding header('Content-Type: text/xml'); to the php file generating the xml did it.